# Finding image filepaths and adding them to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website hosted through Go-Daddy, which also has a MySQL database connected to it through phpMyAdmin. I have images stored in a folder (/images) inside the public home directory (public_html). I need to display these images with the item details associated with them (name, price, description, etc.), which are all stored in the database.

My Question is:

why, when I enter the file path `public_html/images/image1.jpg` in the column of the database for pictures (VARCHAR(100)), does it output the file path instead of the image when a row is output to the website?

Comment: not sure what your asking, you would use the db field in your html img tag . `<img src="$DB_VALUE">` .. `public_html` is the root web path so you can leave tht out

Comment: How are you storing your image in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are storing the path to the image in the database column, not the image itself. So, when you try to display the contents of that column, it displays what is stored in the database - the file path.

To show the image itself you need to pass the database column content, which the image file path, as the `src` property of HTML `IMG` tag.

Something like

```
 <img name="dbImage" src="'.$column_name_here.'" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363102/displaying-an-image-with-path-stored-in-database-in-a-html-template-file-with-ph) for more information.

Comment: please dont suggest the use of mysql*